# Why is Spring MVC so called, when it is not an MVC framework?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

`MVC` describes when the `Observer` pattern is used to allow a model to notify the views about changes.

This is not how **Spring MVC** works.

**Spring MVC** is a [Model2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2) framework because it doesn't notify the views from the model - the controller simply passes the model data to the views and performs the html generation.

So why is it called "**Spring MVC**"?

Comment: Your concept of MVC is too small; you've limited it to a particular implementation (in Swing, presumably). MVC is a architectural pattern prescribing a separation of concerns between model, view, and controller and has many different implementations, many of which don't use the Observer pattern.  The article you've referenced even states that Model 2 designs are frequently associated with MVC architectures.

Comment: True but Model 2 is also frequently associated with EJB but that doesn't mean EJB is necessary to have Model 2. Nevertheless, I take your point that I may be interpreting MVC too narrowly.

Comment: tvanfosson is right, but I can see how you'd get that idea about MVC Michael (namely that it's the model that MUST have some call-back mechanism to tell the VIEW that it's time to update), as I've read countless presentations/articles in which MVC is presented like that (and they're wrong). It's just some people's need to over-architecturize I guess....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observers are not *necessary* in MVC--how the view gets updated is implementation-specific. A controller can just tell the view to render itself, or the view can request a new rendering, which is what happens in almost all web-oriented MVC frameworks.

That said, while most web-oriented MVC frameworks are an *interpretation* of the original idea of MVC, they're still pretty MVC since they have the separation of components, and operate as a synchronous version of it.

Comment: +1 for the word `interpretation`. Good argument.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is a design pattern in which there's a view, a model and a controller. Concerning how the view updates itself on model changes, there's no particula statement saying that there should be an Observer patter there from view to model. Having the view actively re-interrogate the model in order to update itself is in accordance with the MVC spec.

Model2 is one implementation of the MVC design. This is something released by the Java EE guys (as well as Model1 which is non MVC compliant). In short, while Model one said you only had a separation between model on the one side (the beans), and view plus controller on the other (both represented by JSP pages), in the Model2 paradigm you have JSP as the view, beans as the  model and servlets as the controller.

Spring-MVC is called that and not Spring-Model2 becauese model2 is something related to specific Java EE components such as servlets, JSPs and beans, while Spring-MVC encompasses more than that: the controllers are not servlets, the view can be something else besides JSP, etc.